# RStudio git repository disappeared

Tags: r, git, github, version-control

I just updated my Mac OS to Mojave and when I opened up a project I've been working for with a git_hub repository attached. I decided to start a new project with version control. It stated

> Git was not detected on the system path.
>
> To create projects from git repositories you should install Git and then restart RStudio.
>
> Note that if Git is installed and not on the path, then you can specify it's location using Preference Dialog

I noticed that the current project which I have been using version control on no longer has the tab to push updates.

In project settings it states

Version Control System: {(NONE)}

and does not allow any options to change to git. Git is uploaded on my computer, I have restarted r, but I still cannot figure out how to reattach my repository to the project nor attach my new repository to a new project.

Any suggestions for somebody newly learning R

Comment: *"I just updated my Mac OS"* ... sounds like your project directory files were either relocated or the upgrade lost some of your files. If you open a terminal, change to the project directory, and type `ls -al`, do you see the `./.git/` directory?

Comment: The new MacOS doesn't preserve `/usr/include`. You are expected to consult the R-admin manual.

Comment: @r2evans all that is found is a .git and a .gitignore

Comment: I think @42-'s comment is the key. The good news, it sounds like your projects is untouched (which sounded odd to me anyway). Likely culprit: git is not installed or just not in a place that RStudio is looking for it. On the console, type in `which git`. My guess: nothing found. In my windows Rstudio, *Tools > Global Options > Git/SVN* gives me the option to specify where the `git` executable is located. If you can find what that should be and it remains not in your `PATH`, you can force/encourage it here.

Comment: @r2evans when I enter 'which git' into the terminal I get my bash '/user/local/bin/git'. I have used the terminal to add files to commit and have tried to commit through the terminal. It has led me to believe that I simply have lost the git access window. I can't seem to find

Comment: Since you are using RStudio, it recently added support for an embedded terminal. If you start that and type in `which git`, I suspect that it will *not* find your local version, in which case the fix I suggested earlier (*Tools > Global Options > ...*) should work. Regardless, doing that step should not hurt anything. You might need to restart RStudio after setting that variable (I don't know). Have you tried that yet?

Comment: So here's where I am. I have learned the language of git in the terminal to upload it to my github so large thank you to everybody who has helped. I don't know why it says I'm not connected in my RStudio settings and such but for now, I can do it the long way. I have tried to reset it from Global Options but have not had any success as of yet. It is likely just an error on my part but my global access claims that version control is enabled and I have turned it on and off and restarted R but no change. I am just glad that I was able to commit changes through the terminal so I have my version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinstall the command line tools for Mac OS X:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 2):

Point to your local copy of 'git;. Use the terminal to find it:

> which git

On my machine it was:

/usr/local/bin/git

Then under R-studio preferences, select the GIT/SVN panel and use the browse feature to locate and click on git at that location ... hit 'apply/ok' then restart R ... it worked in my case.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else who may deal with this in the future. I am still unable to get git to work directly in the rstudio GUI however using the terminal still works. If the terminal is time consuming I believe in the terminal you can input `>git gui` and it will open a third party window.